# Shopify, where can I find {{ pages.cold-pressed-ocntent-2.content }}

Tags: html, shopify

```
{%comment%}
<header class="section-header">
  <h1 class="section-header__title">{{ page.title }}</h1>
</header>
{%endcomment%}
{% comment %}
  Regular page content goes here.
{% endcomment %}
<div class="rte">
  {{ page.content }}
</div>

<div class="cold-first-sec">
  <div class="cold-video-icon">
 <img src="{{ 'play-btn-icon.png' | asset_url }}"/>
 {% comment %}     <img src="{{ '1.gif' | asset_url }}"/> {% endcomment %} 
  </div>
</div>
<section class="section-contect-three container12">

     {{ pages.cold-pressed-ocntent-2.content }}

</section>
<section class="section-cold-three container12">

     {{ pages.cold-pressed-content-3.content }}

</section>
```

I am looking for `pages.cold-pressed-content-3.content` but it is not listed as a file in my theme. I have searched in Layout, Templates, Sections, Snippets, Assets, Config, Locales. But it is not there, where could it be, what am i missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to go to `settings_data.json`, this is where all the relations are made, is like a list of aliases. And I found the correct template there.